# When I use exec-maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin doesn't work

Tags: java, maven

When I use the Maven plugin `exec-maven-plugin` and `maven-dependency-plugin` at same time, it doesn't work.

`<argument>-javaagent:${co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:jar:jdk8}</argument>`

I receive this error:

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ${co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:jar:jdk8}

What might be wrong?

Comment: Without a pom file it is simply impossible to help and best would be having an example project which shows the problem..

Comment: 1 Answer  :that is my pom.xml

Comment: Add your pom to the question (by editing it). The "answer" will be deleted shortly.